# How to setup dalli cache in test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, dalli

I'm going to use Dalli cache as key-value store.

Usually in production and development environments we have line

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

so then we can use `Rails.cache` construction to read from and write to cache.

But in the test environment usually, we don't have this config line.

What is the right way to set up a cache in a test environment in purpose to test my storing logic?

P.S. I'm using Linux(Ubuntu)

Comment: You can set up a local instance of memcahed but the procedure depends on what operating system you are on.  Are you on Windows / Mac Linux?

Comment: @MarkStratmann, i'm on Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dalli is a client for the caching service (memcached)
set it globally whatever the environment, ie in your config/application.rb

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

caching being deactivated in the test environment is a common approach, check config/environments/test.rb

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

so you can enable it for the test environment, but it could lead to some weird conflicts
best is probably to enable it on the go for a specific specs only:

```
before do # enable caching
  @caching_state = ActionController::Base.perform_caching
  ActionController::Base.perform_caching = true
end

after do # disable caching
  ActionController::Base.perform_caching = @caching_state
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I have assumed you are on Ubuntu and did a google of "ubuntu install memcached rails" and found several pages with details.  Below are the key points.

**To Install memecache**

```
sudo apt-get install memcached
```

**To restart memcahce**

```
/etc/init.d/memcached restart
```